# Stata: Lag length criteria: How can I explain the results?

Tags: selection, criteria, stata, lag

I got different outputs from the code

```
forval i = 1/118 {
    varsoc var`i', maxlag(10)
}
```

that gives AIC,BIC,... lag information criteria, but I don't know how I can interpret them. 
How can I choose the correct number of lags on the basis of all this output?

I know that, if I have only one variable, I've to choose the smallest value of AIC and the others, but what should I do if I have more outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to do.  Minimizing AIC or BIC is one criterion for selecting a lag length.  You have multiple variables; are you trying to fit separate models to each variable or a single vector autoregression?  In the later case, you should use Stata's `varsoc` command with multiple variables and choose the lag that way.  For example,

```
varsoc x y z, maxlag(10)
```

will calculate an optimal lag length (according to AIC, BIC, etc.) for a vector autoregression with variables `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Suppose the answer is 3 lags according to BIC (recommended for VAR).  Then the model can be fit using:

```
var x y z, lags(1 2 3)
```

If you need to restrict certain lags to zero for certain coefficients, use the `constraint` command.  For example, you need the third lag on `x` in the equation for `y` to be zero (maybe there are theoretical reasons for this).  The following will work:

```
constraint 1 [y]L3.x = 0
var x y z, lags(1 2 3) constraints(1)
```